# Problems in the configuration of the web catalog

Tags: orocommerce

The configuration of the web catalog was made to leave as main page, the product page and not the home page.
Follow the steps below:

```
1) go to Marketing / Web Catalogs

2) click on "Edit Content Tree" for the chosen web catalog

3) And change the default content variant for the root tree node. By default, it's set to 
   the "System Page" - "Oro Frontend Root". Set the "System Page Route" to "Oro Product 
   Frontend Prduct Index
```

but I do not get any result with this change I tried to run the following command, in case it generated some change or delete cache, but I still do not see the change I need.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that your message consumers are running. We've checked this case and all works as expected.

Comment: How can I check that the message consumers are running?

Comment: depends on how you run them:) if you run them direct in the console - check that its running:) If they running by supervisor - check in the supervisor logs.

Comment: https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/mq/consumer/

Comment: https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/mq/supervisord/